# How to remove a criteria in Spring Mongo Query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a Mongo query `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query` with one criteria and I want to update this criteria by adding the same criteria with different value:

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("clientName").is("client2"));
```

But this throws:

> Method threw
>   'org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException'
>   exception. Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you
>   can't add a second 'clientName' criteria. Query already contains
>   '{"clientName": "client1"}'

I've tried to remove the criteria using:

```
query.getQueryObject().remove("clientName")
```

But it seems like it returns a copy of the criteria and it didn't remove the criteria. I'm still getting the same exception.

How can I properly remove a criteria in Mongo query?

Comment: Any update on this? Would be nice if you could post your solution here. I have similar case and need to remove one specific Criteria from query that can be complex with multiple and and or operators. Building new query would also be complex instead of simply getting to remove one Criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow:

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public Query queryName(Type1 value1, Type2 value2) {
    Query query = new Query(new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where("field1").is(value1), Criteria.where("field2").is(value2)));
}
```

Please note that you can change"orOperator" with "andOperator" based on what you need, otherwise you can use a single criteria.

I think that, instead of deleting a criteria, you should create a new query using for example the function above.

Comment: Sometimes I have many criteria in my query and would rather avoid making a new query.